# How to prevent linebreaks after an inline image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, line-breaks

I noticed that my browser may set a line break after an `<img>` tag, even if this image tag is followed by `&nbsp;`:

```html
<p style="width: 12ex; font-family:monospace;">
  12345678 <img style="width: 2ex" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/25px-Smiley.svg.png">&nbsp;123
</p>
```

The smiley should be on the second line, because the image tag is followed by `nbsp;`. I can force this behavior by adding a `<span>` with `white-space: nowrap`:

```html
<p style="width: 12ex; font-family:monospace;">
 12345678 <span style="white-space: nowrap"><img style="width: 2ex" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/25px-Smiley.svg.png">&nbsp;123</span>
 </span>
</p>
```

Is there a solution without adding an additional `<span>` tag? For example: Is there a CSS statement for `<img>` to prevent line breaks after it?

**Note:** The CSS of the `<p>` should not be altered. I only use it to simulate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Cerbrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) suggested, on can use `display: inline-block` to the `<img>` tag:

```html
<p style="width: 12ex; font-family:monospace;">
  12345678 <img style="width: 2ex;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/25px-Smiley.svg.png">&nbsp;123
</p>
```

This works for Chromium 36 and 38 (and maybe also for any other webkit browser).

Unfortunately it does not work for the current release of Firefox 33 and also not for the current nightly version of Firefox (see also [bug 139723](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=139723) and [bug 172819](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=172819) for similar bugs of Firefox).

*Sitenote:* I answered my own question, because [this suggested edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6092240).

Answer (score 2):

Yea, just use css's `display: inline-block`

```css
img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-family:monospace;">
  sometext<img style="width: 2ex" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/25px-Smiley.svg.png">&nbsp;sometext
</p>
```

Just make sure the `p` is wide enough, so it doesn't need to wrap. (I removed the `width` style)

This doesn't appear to work in Firefox 33.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work for me. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c5r47grf/1/). I added `display: inline-block;` to the image tag (followed by `&nbsp;`), but the line break still occurs after it... (the smiley should be on the second line)

Comment: I guess your code example only works, because you removed the `width` style from the `<p>` tag. But this declaration is necessary to simulate the need for a line break (If the `<p>` tag is wide enough to fit the whole text into it, we cannot see the line breaking behavior of the image...). That's why I downvoted your answer...

Comment: Actually, the smiley in [that fiddle you linked](http://jsfiddle.net/c5r47grf/1/) is on the second line for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox version 33.0 Your are right: On my chromium browser the smiley is on the second line... A bug in Firefox?!

Comment: I can only upvote your answer after you edit it. So maybe add a note, that it do not work for the current firefox 33.0 version...

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p style="font-family:monospace;">
  sometext<img style="width: 2ex;display:inline-block;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/25px-Smiley.svg.png">&nbsp;sometext
</p>
```

Comment: Why did you add `display:inline` also to the `<p>` tag?

Comment: I just tested it: Your code only works, if there is `display:inline;` set for the surrounding `<p>` tag. But normally an inline behavior of the `<p>` tag is not intended... (that's why I downvoted your answer – thanks for it anyway ;-) )

Comment: Sorry, I was kinda busy. Edited it

Comment: No prob. Unfortunately the problem is still unsolved (see my comments to Cerbrus answer)